# Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;'

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I tried to run an imported project in [this repo](https://github.com/hadeelalseni/ud867/tree/master/FinalProject)

but I got this error:

```
Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I used android studio version 3.4.1, and Gradle version 5.1.1. 
anyone can help please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was getting the same error and fixed it by updating a dependency in the backend module:

```
classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
```

Comment: I am not sure why this has not been accepted as the answer, but it did solve the issue for me as well.

Comment: I was updating a very old project. I accepted all the android studio gradle suggested changes and updates. I then hit the error " cannot find api()". This was fixed by adding in the "apply plugin: 'java-library'. Then I hit the above error and the change you suggested helped the build progress. Hope this helps someone and thank you .

Comment: after two hours found this ans. Thank you.

Comment: In my case Spring Boot is not compatible with the Gradle version my server uses. #saynotoframeworks